# can not set spark executor number larger than nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I followed instructions on 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

where I set --num-executors to 13, even though I only have 8 worker nodes. In the spark program I explicitly set high number of partitions

```
val myPartitioner = new HashPartitioner(20)
```

The spark program runs fine, but in the executor console, it only shows 8 executors at all times. Shouldn't it show 13?

Comment: how many cores do you have on each worker ?

Comment: The same with memory. How much memory do you have in your cluster and how much memory you requested per each worker?

Comment: are you running in stand-alone or YARN cluster mode?

Comment: 8 cores per worker. 30GB total memory per node. I allocate --executor-memory 14G. --master yarn-cluster. How would these parameters affect the outcome? The question is why I only see 8 executors.

Answer (score 0):

The --num-executors mentioned in the [link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) is applicable to YARN cluster mode.

Try setting the following environment variable in conf/spark-env.sh to increase the number of workers in stand-alone or other cluster mode,

> **SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES**
>
> Number of worker instances to run on each machine (default: 1). You can make this more than 1 if you have have very large machines and would like multiple Spark worker processes. If you do set this, make sure to also set SPARK_WORKER_CORES explicitly to limit the cores per worker, or else each worker will try to use all the cores.

Comment: does number of worker instances mean number of executors per node? So,  the default of 1 is why I can not get the 13 executors?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The number of worker instances mean number of executors per node.

Comment: similar question.  why would I need to set both --num-executors and SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES ? if you set SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES to 2, and you have 8 nodes, then it should automatically know there are 16 executors, right? by the way, I am using yarn cluster mode. Maybe you are saying SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES is not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is set to **false**. By default it is set to false, so if you did not change it, it should be fine.

Modify the number of executors by adding `spark.executor.instances 13` in spark-defaults.conf. Or by adding in you code:

```
conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("yarn-client")
                ....
                .set("spark.executor.instances", "13")
```

Comment: so why would I need to set both --num-executors and spark.executor.instances to 13? what is the implication of setting only one of the two, or different numbers for them?

Comment: You don´t have to set both. They are supposed to be the same thing. You can find more about Configuring Spark on Yarn here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html    In that table you can find spark.executor.instances as a config that is specific to Spark on YARN